# Does one's tax transcript indicate whether taxes were paid?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, payment

I looked at my [tax transcript](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/get-transcript) in the US, I could see the amount I was supposed to pay, but I couldn't see the amount I actually paid:

[image]

or do these lines also represent the amount I actually paid?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you have appears to be your [tax return transcript](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/transcript-types-and-ways-to-order-them), which includes data from the return itself and the calculations the IRS did to verify the return. It does not show actual amounts paid (or refunds issued) with or subsequent to the return -- for that you need the tax *account* transcript.

The lines you are pointing to on the tax return transcript are IRS recalculations of the amount you owed on the return. If you completed the return correctly, they should match the amount you entered yourself. If not, the IRS is probably sending you a letter explaining that they adjusted your return. These calculations are to establish what you owed and are independent of whether you have paid it.